# How _exactly_ does one integrate DTFoundation into another iOS project?

Tags: ios

I am trying to debug a project where I suspect UI operations are being called in background threads. This link: [UIViewController animations stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281097/uiviewcontroller-animations-stop-working) describes how to use a `DTFoundation` code to detect if UI operations are called in background threads but I can't figure out how to integrate. I don't use Pods - its an `XCode` project for another app. I tried dragging `DTFoundation.xcodeproj`, adding it to target but I just can't get it to work. The app builds but the library does not. Any sage advice?

Comment: What did you try? All you have to do is add the library project as a framework to your project and link your project with the output of that project. It's pretty straightforward, and any tutorial on how to create a static lib shows it.

Comment: Leo, Im not an experience iOS person. Here is what I tried: First I pulled in DTFoundation.xcodeproj into my existing project - I could not figure out how to build the libraries this way. Next, I opened up DTFoundation.xcodeproj as a new project and compiled - it says it compiled but there was no build directory and there was no .a file generated - it just created the test apps on my phone.

Comment: What I also can't figure out is do I compile the entire DTFoundation code or just the iOS directory?

Comment: I've made some progress - I've managed to get the relevant files working. I just copied DTLog, UIView+DTDebug, DTOBjectBlockExecutor and NSObject+DTRuntime .m and .h files into my current project and everything compiled and executed fine.I skipped importing the rest of DTFramework files.  Do I need to do anything else to start trapping UIKit calls? I don't see logs being generated on the console and neither does the app stop when the calls are made.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with that framework, so I cannot help you there. Better ask in the framework's site.

Comment: No worries Leo, I finally managed to get it working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, for anyone looking to use DTFoundation to trap UIKit calls outside of the main thread, here is how (NOTE: This is ONLY for trapping UIKit calls - not to avail of all the other DTFoundation utilities).

1) Download DTFoundation code from here https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTFoundation and unzip it somewhere

2) In XCode, open up your existing project you want to debug, and just copy the following .h and .m files to your project from the unzipped DTFoundation code: UIView+DTDebug, DTLog, DTObjectBlockExecutor, NSObject+DTRunTime
(That's 8 files - each name above has a corresponding .h and .m)

3) Now go to your AppDelegate.mm file in your project and in the  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function add

```
  [UIView toggleViewMainThreadChecking];
```

4) Next up, set a breakpoint inside UIView+DTDebug.m at at -

(void)methodCalledNotFromMainThread:(NSString *)methodName

You will now be all set to run your master code and any time a UI operation is called outside the main thread, your code will break at this point. Now all you need to do is look at the stack trace - the first function inside your own project code (typically several lines into the trace) is the offending code. Wrap it inside

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ <Offending UI code goes here> });
```

or any other way appropriate

Enjoy! This framework save many hours of flubbing around